# Can any expert of SQL check my SQL query, it didn't work

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
SELECT 
usertype,
CONCAT(start_station_name, " to", end_station_name) AS route
ROUND (AVG(cast(tripduration AS int64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
group by start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
order by num_trip desc 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was just going to post this as a comment, but wanted to offer some formatting advice too

```
SELECT 
    usertype,
    CONCAT(start_station_name, " to", end_station_name) AS route,
    ROUND (AVG(CAST(tripduration AS int64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY
    start_station_name,
    end_station_name,
    usertype
ORDER BY num_trip DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

I think your issue was just the missing commas in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` sections, but I also recommend capitalizing all syntax and separating lists by indented new lines -- these things help spot errors